# Proving that if $\lambda (\{ f^\prime = 0\}) = 0$, then $f$ is increasing

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, riemann-integration

I am trying to show that

> Let $f:[a,b]\to R$ be a differentiable map, with $f'(x) \geq 0$, for all $x \in [a,b].$ If the set $U = A = \left\{x \in [a,b] : f'(x)=0 \right\}$ has null content, prove that $f$ is an increasing map.

I tried to start this proof by proving the thesis by contradiction. Let $f$ be a non-increasing map. Then, if we take $[x,y] \subset [a,b]$, there exists $y>0$ such that $f(y)=f(x)$ right? I got the tip that for all $z \in [x,y]$, $f(x)+f(z)=f(y)$ but I can't understand why does that happen. Can anybody give me an idea if why is this valid? Thank you so much!

Comment: Was your tip supposed to be $f(x) = f(z) = f(y)$?  It makes no sense to conclude $f(x) + f(z) = f(y)$ from $f(x)=f(y)$ unless $f(x)=0$.

Comment: I edited my answer

Comment: Yes, that is where I wanna get, once if $f(x)=0$, that would mean that the interval $[x,y]$ has no null content, what is a contradiction, because it actually does.

Comment: There's no way I see to conclude $f(x) = 0$ even in the contradiction.  However, it's easy to conclude via the mean value theorem that $f(x) = f(z) = f(y)$ for all $z \in [x,y]$ if we assume $f(x) = f(y)$.  This is what I show below.

Comment: Ok then! In your proof you are also assuming that $f$ is non-crescent right?

Comment: I'm assuming $f : [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable, $f' \geq 0$, and $\lambda(\{f' = 0\}) = 0$.  That's it.

Comment: Got it. I'll analyse the cases $x>y$ and $x=0$ usint the mean value theorem as well.

Answer (score 2):

It's obvious that $x\leq y$ implies $f(x)\leq f(y)$. The challenge is to replace $\leq$ with $<$.

$\\$

Suppose you had $x<y$. Then, because $(x,y)$ has positive Lebesgue measure, there must be some $c\in(x,y)$ such that $f'(c)>0$.

Given that $f'(c)>0$, there exists $r>0$ such that $f(c+z)>f(c)$ for all $z\in(0,r)$ and also $c+r<y$.

Thus, $f(y)\geq f(c+r)>f(c)\geq f(x)$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x < y$.  By the mean value theorem, $f(y) = f(x) + (y-x)f'(c)$ for some $c$.  Since $(y-x)f'(c) \geq 0$, it follows that $f(x) \leq f(y)$.

Towards a contradiction, suppose $f(x) = f(y)$.

For any $z \in (x,y)$, by the mean value theorem again, we have $f(x) \leq f(z) \leq f(y) = f(x)$, which implies $f(z) = f(x)$.  Differentiating with respect to $z$, we find $f'(z) = 0$ for all $z \in (x,y)$, so that $$\lambda(\{f' = 0\}) \geq \lambda((x,y)) = y-x > 0,$$ which is the contradiction.

It follows that $f(x)\neq f(y)$, so $f(x) < f(y)$.